# Rails 6 PaperTrail pull logs from only one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Let's assume I'm tracking two models in my Rails 6 app using PaperTrail gem - `Book` and `User`. Now I want to generate CSV file with logs only which includes only `Book` models activities. How to how to pull versions for only one model e.g. `Book` ?

```
# models
class Book
  has_paper_trail
end

class User
  has_paper_trail
end

#call method for csv_generator service

    def call
      CSV.generate(col_sep: ';', write_headers: true, headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
        PaperTrail::Version.includes([:item]).limit(50).order(id: :desc).each do |v|
          tracked_data(v)
          csv << [v.created_at.in_time_zone('CET'),
                  v.event,
                  version.whodunnit,
                  @new_data_value]
        end
      end
    end
```

Now I get logs from both Book and User models instead of only `Book`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default migration adds an `item_type` column which is used to track the tables.

In the given case you can do: `PaperTrail::Version.where(item_type: 'Book')` which will find you all versions for all changes in the book table.

If you want to do per instance of book it would be just:

```
Book.all.each do |book|
  book.versions
end
```